# In which other Delphi versions does the for loop with Cardinals fail?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009, delphi-2007, delphi-xe

Please help me regression test, and determine in Which Delphi versions the code below fails.

**Edit:** *I know there is a compiler hint for it; it was in fact found in a project I inherited that somehow had the compiler hints turned off (something I see a lot of people do, as they think compiler hints are always harmless, this case shows it is not).

Still I want to know in which Delphi versions this compiler anomaly is present for documentation purposes.*

```
[DCC Hint] QC90921_SO4717399TestCase.pas(47): H2135 FOR or WHILE loop executes zero times - deleted
```

In Delphi XE, 2009, 2007, and 5, it fails with the output below.
I didn't have time yet to investigate other Delphi versions.
Please help me with that, and answer with which other Delphi versions it fails as well.

```
Low/High const fail: 0
Low/High hex literal fail: 0
Low/High decimal literal fail: 0
```

This is the code that is also part of [QC 90921](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=90921):

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils;

var
  CardinalIndex: Cardinal;
  CardinalFirst: Cardinal;
  CardinalLast: Cardinal;
  Count: Int64;
  Target: Int64;
begin
  try
    Target := High(Cardinal);
    Inc(Target);

    Count := 0;
    for CardinalIndex := Low(CardinalIndex) to High(CardinalIndex) do
      Inc(Count);
    if Target <> Count then
      Writeln('Low/High const fail: ', Count);

    Count := 0;
    for CardinalIndex := 0 to $FFFFFFFF do
      Inc(Count);
    if Target <> Count then
      Writeln('Low/High hex literal fail: ', Count);

    Count := 0;
    for CardinalIndex := 0 to 4294967295 do
      Inc(Count);
    if Target <> Count then
      Writeln('Low/High decimal literal fail: ', Count);

    Count := 0;
    CardinalFirst := Low(Cardinal);
    CardinalLast := High(Cardinal);
    for CardinalIndex := CardinalFirst to CardinalLast do
      Inc(Count);
    if Target <> Count then
      Writeln('Low/High variable fail: ', Count);

    Count := 0;
    CardinalFirst := 0;
    CardinalLast := $FFFFFFFF;
    for CardinalIndex := CardinalFirst to CardinalLast do
      Inc(Count);
    if Target <> Count then
      Writeln('hex literal Variable fail: ', Count);

    Count := 0;
    CardinalFirst := 0;
    CardinalLast := 4294967295;
    for CardinalIndex := CardinalFirst to CardinalLast do
      Inc(Count);
    if Target <> Count then
      Writeln('decimal literal Variable fail: ', Count);

    Write('Press <Enter>');
    Readln;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

**Edit:** *summary of the answers; it fails in these Delphi versions:*

- 5
- 6
- 7
- 2006
- 2007
- 2009
- 2010
- XE

--jeroen

Comment: FWIW it is documented, see the bottom of: http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/devcommon/cm_null_loop_xml.html

Comment: Your problem is that your for loops terminate instantly instead of running for 2^32 iterations? But only if the start/end values are compiletime constants, but not if they are variables.

Comment: @Sertac - you should post this link as the/an answer.

Comment: @Deltics - It's a bit of a speculation since I haven't done any tests, but answered anyway.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: thx, I knew the cause, but good you phrased it, as I forgot to.

Comment: Same output with Delphi 7, first two loops are deleted (FOR or WHILE loop executes zero times - deleted). See Sertac Akyuz's answer.

Comment: @The_Fox: please make that an answer, as this is specifically the kind of answers I asked for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess, since this is a documented defect, all versions where `High(Cardinal)` > `High(Longint)` (Delphi 4 and up) would exhibit the behavior.

From "[H2135: FOR or WHILE loop executes zero times - deleted (Delphi)](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/devcommon/cm_null_loop_xml.html)":

> You may see this warning if a FOR loop increments its control variable from a value within the range of Longint to a value outside the range of Longint. For example:
> `var I: Cardinal;
> begin
>   For I := 0 to $FFFFFFFF do
> ...`
> This results from a limitation in the compiler which you can work around by replacing the FOR loop with a WHILE loop.

Comment: Thanks for finding this; I tried, but forgot to search for the HEX constant (duh <g>). I added it as a workaround to the QC.

Comment: I'm accepting your answer, as it is 'outside the box' thinking. I have upvoted the other answers as they are valuable too.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is a real SO question that Jeff would approve of, but here is the output from D2010:

```
Low/High const fail: 0
Low/High literal fail: 0
Press <Enter>
```

Delphi 6 produces the same output.

Comment: Thx. We'll see what the rest of SO (including the moderators) think about this question.

Answer (score 1):

Same output with Delphi 7, first two loops are deleted (FOR or WHILE loop executes zero times - deleted). See Sertac Akyuz's answer.

Edit:

Same with Turbo Delphi 2006, first three loops are deleted with the same hint.

Answer (score 1):

Delphi 2006:

```
[Pascal Hint] Project1.dpr(20): H2135 FOR or WHILE loop executes zero times - deleted
[Pascal Hint] Project1.dpr(26): H2135 FOR or WHILE loop executes zero times - deleted
[Pascal Hint] Project1.dpr(32): H2135 FOR or WHILE loop executes zero times - deleted
```

Output:

```
Low/High const fail: 0
Low/High hex literal fail: 0
Low/High decimal literal fail: 0
```